# Flat the result after leftJoinAndMapOne with typeorm

Tags: mysql, nestjs, left-join, typeorm, query-builder

I'm using typeorm for nestjs to query data from mySql database.
I have 3 tables name: post, assets_post and asset
Now I create a query build to get data, like this:

```
private getAllQueryProcess(
    request: PostRequestDto,
  ): SelectQueryBuilder<PostEntity> {
    const queryBuilder = this.postEntity.createQueryBuilder('p');

    queryBuilder.where('p.id is not null');

    queryBuilder.leftJoinAndMapOne(
      'p.id',
      AssetsPostEntity,
      'ap',
      'ap.post = p.id',
    );

    queryBuilder.leftJoinAndMapOne(
      'ap.asset',
      AssetEntity,
      'a',
      'a.id = ap.asset',
    );

    queryBuilder.select([
      'p.id',
      'p.title',
      'ap.asset',
      'ap.post',
      'a.url',
    ]);

    queryBuilder.groupBy('p.id');

    queryBuilder.orderBy('p.id', 'ASC');

    return queryBuilder;
  }
```

The problem is the result will be an array of object like this:

```
{
    "id": {
        "asset": {
            "url": "https://url"
        },
        "post": 3
    },
    "title": "Some title",
}
```

I think I used the query build wrong way because I want to get a result that flat all the field, like:

```
{
    "id": 3, //id from main table: post
    "url": "https://url", // url from table asset
    "title": "Some title",
}
```

How to fix this issue? I can mapping the result after getMany() or getRawMany() but are there any solution to mapping the data in the queryBuilder?